# adb I/O Error, possible corruption

Tags: android, database, sqlite, calendar, adb

I am struggling to fix an issue I have. Basically my Galaxy S3 has just up and decided that Google Calendar will now crash whenever I open it. After examining the system log, stack trace, etc... it appears to be stemming from the app trying to access `/data/data/com.google.android.calendar/databases/<database>.db`, of course with a specific database name.

When I `cd` into the folder by using adb in root mode I find the folder lib, cache and a file named databases. The other two folders perform normally but databases is weird, it does not auto-complete with tab and using any form of file operation on it (such as `less`, `rm`, etc...) results in an `I/O Error`.

I think this is an oddly corrupted file that is causing the problem, particularly as it appears to stay even when I uninstall Google Calendar. Any help would be most appreciated in getting this sorted as I could really do with getting my calendar back.

Long display of results:

```
root@m0:/data/data/com.google.android.calendar # ls
databases
root@m0:/data/data/com.google.android.calendar # rm databases
rm failed for databases, I/O error
255|root@m0:/data/data/com.google.android.calendar # rm -rf databases
rm failed for databases, I/O error
1|root@m0:/data/data/com.google.android.calendar # cd databases
/system/bin/sh: cd: /data/data/com.google.android.calendar/databases: I/O error
2|root@m0:/data/data/com.google.android.calendar # 
2|root@m0:/data/data/com.google.android.calendar # sqlite3 databases                                                                                 
SQLite version 3.7.11 2012-03-20 11:35:50
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .databases
Error: unable to open database "databases": unable to open database file
1|root@m0:/data/data/com.google.android.calendar #
```

Regards,
Ybrad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh,

Turns out that if you uninstall the app, rename the folder containing the corrupted file and then re-install everything goes swimmingly.

No idea what caused it or even what is wrong but hey, I have my calendar back.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to a friend on his Moto X Force, Instagram kept crashing. He was using LineageOS 7.1, we wiped everything and installed the original firmware (through TRWP) and when we was installing the package, it returned IO Error on "data/data/com.instagram.android/analytics/xxxxxxxx.pending". We formatted the /data partition but the problem persisted.
We installed the original firmware along with Magisk, installed Root Explorer and renamed the "com.instagram.android" folder to "insta.broken", uninstalled and reinstalled the app and voilá, working again.